# Cannot link against LibUSB Visual Studio 2013. Linker error 2019 (LNK2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dll, libusb

Apparently there's nothing I have more difficulty with than flipping switches in VS and using DLLs. No matter how many times I do it, I can never seem to get it right.

Anyway, I'm trying to link LibUSB against a test application. I've downloaded the Windows binaries from [LibUSB.info](http://libusb.info/) and now I'd like to link it to my test project. My directory structure is as follows:

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Local Disk
Volume serial number is 00000200 1C56:6A00
C:.
|   LibUSBTest.sdf
|   LibUSBTest.sln
|   out.txt
|   
+---Debug
|       LibUSBTest.pdb
|       
+---ipch
|   +---libusbtest-291f707a
|   |       libusbtest-85afab4d.ipch
|   |       
|   \---libusbtest-e65e4917
|           libusbtest-85afab4d.ipch
|           
+---libusb
|   |   libusb-1.0.def
|   |   README.txt
|   |   
|   +---examples
|   |   +---bin32
|   |   |       fxload.exe
|   |   |       listdevs.exe
|   |   |       xusb.exe
|   |   |       
|   |   +---bin64
|   |   |       fxload.exe
|   |   |       listdevs.exe
|   |   |       xusb.exe
|   |   |       
|   |   \---source
|   |           ezusb.c
|   |           ezusb.h
|   |           fxload.c
|   |           listdevs.c
|   |           stdint.h
|   |           xusb.c
|   |           
|   +---include
|   |   \---libusb-1.0
|   |           libusb.h
|   |           
|   +---MinGW32
|   |   +---dll
|   |   |       libusb-1.0.dll
|   |   |       libusb-1.0.dll.a
|   |   |       
|   |   \---static
|   |           libusb-1.0.a
|   |           
|   +---MinGW64
|   |   +---dll
|   |   |       libusb-1.0.dll
|   |   |       libusb-1.0.dll.a
|   |   |       
|   |   \---static
|   |           libusb-1.0.a
|   |           
|   +---MS32
|   |   +---dll
|   |   |       libusb-1.0.dll
|   |   |       libusb-1.0.lib
|   |   |       libusb-1.0.pdb
|   |   |       
|   |   \---static
|   |           libusb-1.0.lib
|   |           
|   \---MS64
|       +---dll
|       |       libusb-1.0.dll
|       |       libusb-1.0.lib
|       |       libusb-1.0.pdb
|       |       
|       \---static
|               libusb-1.0.lib
|               
\---LibUSBTest
    |   LibUSBTest.cpp
    |   LibUSBTest.vcxproj
    |   LibUSBTest.vcxproj.filters
    |   ReadMe.txt
    |   stdafx.cpp
    |   stdafx.h
    |   targetver.h
    |   
    \---Debug
        |   LibUSBTest.Build.CppClean.log
        |   LibUSBTest.log
        |   LibUSBTest.obj
        |   LibUSBTest.pch
        |   stdafx.obj
        |   vc120.idb
        |   vc120.pdb
        |   
        \---LibUSBTest.tlog
                cl.command.1.tlog
                CL.read.1.tlog
                CL.write.1.tlog
                LibUSBTest.lastbuildstate
                link-cvtres.read.1.tlog
                link-cvtres.write.1.tlog
                link-rc.read.1.tlog
                link-rc.write.1.tlog
                link.command.1.tlog
                link.read.1.tlog
                link.write.1.tlog
                unsuccessfulbuild


            |   vc120.idb
        |   vc120.pdb
        |   
        \---LibUSBTest.tlog
                cl.command.1.tlog
                CL.read.1.tlog
                CL.write.1.tlog
                LibUSBTest.lastbuildstate
                link-cvtres.read.1.tlog
                link-cvtres.write.1.tlog
                link-rc.read.1.tlog
                link-rc.write.1.tlog
                link.command.1.tlog
                link.read.1.tlog
                link.write.1.tlog
                unsuccessfulbuild
```

At the top of my source code, I've defined `#pragma comment(lib, "libusb-1.0.lib")` to add the library dependency.

Under **Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories** I've added `$(SolutionDir)libusb\MS32\dll\` and for **Include Directories** I've added `$(SolutionDir)libusb\include\libusb-1.0\`

Just to be safe, under **Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories** I've added `$(SolutionDir)libusb\include\libusb-1.0\`

Finally, under **Linker->General-> Additional Library Directories** I've added `$(SolutionDir)libusb\MS32\dll\`

I'm assuming I need to copy the DLL and/or Lib file somewhere in the project directory, but even doing that manually hasn't helped matters.

---

**Edit: Output Window Results**

The output window caused me to reach the character limit, so I unfortunately had to resort to using [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/S9u3nTFq) for that part.

Comment: Please post the exact error from the Output window (alt-2).

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the location of the dll.

Comment: For additional library directories try including `$(SolutionDir)libusb\MS32\dll\libusb-1.0.lib`

Comment: @drescherjm coming right up

Comment: @sebenalern No luck on that end

Comment: @drescherjm Added the output window. Had to resort to using pastebin due to character count limitations.

Comment: So, interestingly, I added the library name to the **Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies** list rather than using a `#pragma`. Not ideal, but it apparently worked. Not sure why the pragma would cause issues; I've used it in the past

Comment: Just an FYI, the pragma used is as follows: `#pragma comment(lib, "libusb-1.0.lib")`